# Looping function if the function result is empty

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I am confused to solve my code...
Somebody, can you please help me...

Here is my code, so far...

```
    $r = get_pht_desc($wordString);

    if (empty($r)) {

        while (count($r) < 1 ) {
            $r1 = get_pht_desc($wordString);
            print_r ($r1);
        }

    } else {    
        print_r ($r);   
    }
```

What I want is :
If the result of my Function **$r = get_pht_desc($wordString)** is empty, it will **repeat the function** until the result is not empty or greater than zero.

**Note**: *result of **$r** is an array, so I used **count** to check if the result is empty or not*

I tried a lot of way, I think it's the way but still didn't work. 
The while function gave me result

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )....
```

Until Unlimited...

Thanks in advance

Comment: the result of that fucntion from **$wordString**, there are two possibilities of array.. 

`array ()` -> empty

or 

`array ([0] xxx )` -> not emty

Comment: Why repeat function calls with the same parameter? It should return the same (empty) result as you shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe Below Code

```
$r = array();
while (empty($r)) {
    $r = get_pht_desc($wordString);
}
print_r ($r);
```

but i think it will be endless loop is get_pht_desc($wordString) return empty result bcoz might every time it return same results.

Comment: i think you also need ti put some delay in side while loop to avoid multiple call in 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is that `$r` should not be empty; your loop, which is entered only if `$r` is empty,  is designed to guarantee that `$r` is non-empty upon exit.

Therefore you can just print $r *once* at the end:

```
$r = get_pht_desc($wordString);

if (empty($r)) {
    while (count($r) < 1 ) {
        $r1 = get_pht_desc($wordString);

}

// $r is always filled now. No need to put the print 
// in the else part.
print_r ($r);
```

As a matter of style: PHP has do-while loops which you can use here: You need one read in any case, and want to check only *after* the read whether `$r` is empty:

```
do { $r1 = get_pht_desc($wordString); } while (count($r) < 1 );

// $r is always filled now. No need to put the print 
// in the else part.
print_r ($r);
```

This looks neat to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly use this instead

```
$r = get_pht_desc($wordString);

foreach( $r as $i => $result ){
  if( !empty($result) ){
    print_r($result):
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it is too dangerous if you don't put limit on the number of times this function gonna check for data($r).
I've added limit(e.g. 10) function will be called 10 times at max(to save infinite looping). You can also add sleep inside loop to wait for few seconds and check again(if you'll not add sleep it will call function 10 times within miliseconds).

try this code:

```html
$r = array() 
$count = 0;

do{  
$r = get_pht_desc($wordString);
$count++;
} while(!empty($r) && $count <= 10)

print_r($r);
```